# Window CanResize,but the MinWidth and MinHeight is not work

Tags: wpf, window

I have set `MinWidth` and  `MinHeight`, but it not works when I draged the edge, the window can resize to smaller.

```
WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" 
AllowsTransparency="False" 
Background="Transparent"
WindowStyle="None" 
WindowState="Normal"  
ResizeMode="CanResize"
MinWidth="1188"
MinHeight="610"
Width="1188" 
Height="610"
```

Comment: I want it can resize bigger not smaller

Comment: I am not able to replicate your problem. Setting the `MinWidth` and `MinHeight` should do the trick. You'll have to add some more code for us to help you. Are you sure you're not changing the value of these properties somewhere else?

Comment: I found the solution,thank you!

Comment: And what is the solution?